# Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reduce, deprecated

recently i had this error in my browser's console: ***Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers***

so i was trying to solve it for few hours but nothing helped ...

from the very beginning when i created this script i copied some parts of it from the other my script that i created half a year ago or so... then i found some functions deprecated
and tried to upgrade them...

my old redux-store.js script was like this:

```
...
let reducers = combineReducers({

     auth: auth_reducer,
     admin: admin_reducer,
     index: index_reducer
})


const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
    reducers, 
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
    )
);
...
```

but then i changed (upgraded) it and error from title appeared...
[image: error]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

nothing helped untill i changed *argument name* in function **configureStore()**  from **reducers** to just **reducer**

like this:

```
...
let reducers = combineReducers({
     book: booking_reducer,
     admin: admin_reducer,
})

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = configureStore(
        {reducer:reducers},
        composeEnhancers(
            applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
        )
    );
...
```

I hope this post will help someone to save hours of debugging ;)

Answer (score 3):

`configureStore` is actually used differently and will automatically set up the dev tools and thunks. You also don't need combineReducers.

You just do (really remove all the other code you showed there!):

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer:{
     book: booking_reducer,
     admin: admin_reducer,
  }
})
```

Also, this is pretty much a nudge that your whole application might benefit from modern Redux patterns, as modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer logic or connect any more. As a consequence it's 1/4 of the code.

I'd recommend reading [Why Redux Toolkit is How To Use Redux Today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and going through the official [Redux Essentials Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update, createStore is not used anymore.
Instead of it, configureStore is used. I try to pass a reducer argument as a function but, it does not work. So, i create like

```
const store = configureStore({ reducer: counterReducer });
```

A friendly abstraction over the standard Redux createStore function that adds good defaults to the store setup for a better development experience.
[ConfigureStore](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

const store = configureStore({reducer})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error arises if you write "reducers" instead of "reducer".

```
export const store= configureStore({
    reducer:{
        posts:postsReducer

    }
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).